# Laravel Eloquent Relation to Builder

Tags: eloquent, eloquent-relationship

In my Laravel project

I have a `Sale` model with `payments` Relation

```
public function payments(): Relation
{
    return $this->hasMany(Payment::class);
}
```

now I want this function

```
private function getPaymentsQuery() 
{
    return $this
            ->payments()
            ->where('a', 1);
}
```

so I can chain it further like this

```
$sale->getPaymentsQuery()->where('b', 1)->get();
```

The idea is working, but getPaymentsQuery function returns a class

> \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

but I want it to be

> \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder

Because Relation, as you know, can also be accessed as a property, and property can be used in eager loading and this will bring me to errors one day.

Answer (score 3):

false alarm the class

> \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

has a method just for that

```
->getQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case :

```
QueryBuilder::for($category->products()->getQuery())->get();
```